# pandas fillna on sub-selection of data using multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, nan, multiple-conditions

I have a dataframe. The two main columns i'm looking at are 'survival' and 'alive_at_1'. I want to fill the missing values in 'alive_at_1' with zero ONLY where survival is less than 12 (months)

I make a sub-selection:

```
df[(df.alive_at_1.isnull()) & (df.survival <= 12)]

 survival  still_alive  age_at_heart_attack  pericardial_effusion  fractional_shortening  \
   10.0          0.0                 57.0               0.0         0.24
    9.0          0.0                 73.0               0.0         0.12
   12.0          0.0                 67.0               1.0         0.11   
   12.0          0.0                 61.0               1.0         0.19 

epss  lvdd  wall_motion_score  wall_motion_index  \
14.8   5.26              18.00               1.38   
NaN    6.78              16.67               1.39   
10.3   4.68              11.00               1.00   
13.2   5.04              19.00               1.73   

 alive_at_1  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN
```

now I just want to fill those NaNs in 'alive_at_1', but NOT the one in 'epss'.

I have tried these methods (as well as variations on them) and they do not work (i've tried both `.ix` and `.loc`):

```
df.ix[(df.alive_at_1.isnull()) & (df.survival <= 12), 'alive_at_1'].fillna(0, inplace = True)

df.ix[(df.alive_at_1.isnull()) & (df.survival <= 12), -1].fillna(0, inplace = True)

df.ix[(df.alive_at_1.isnull()) & (df.survival <= 12), 'alive_at_1'] = 0

df.ix[(df.alive_at_1.isnull()) & (df.survival <= 12)].fillna({'alive_at_1':0}, inplace = True)
```

my questions are

- what's the best way to do this (i don't want to just manually input indices but if that's the only way i will)
- and why are the ways i've tried not working??

thanks!

Comment: How are they *not working*? What is the error or undesired result?

Comment: nothing happens. There is no error, but when i look at the Dataframe the NaNs are still there.

Comment: Try replacing the `.ix` from third attempt with `.loc`.

Comment: yep totally worked ... guess i didn't try that. Any Idea why it needs to be so specific?